# How to handle missing fields in client messages in DDP?

Tags: json, meteor, websocket, ddp

I'm writing a DDP server. I read through the spec but seems to me unclear about what to do if the client sends a malformed message.

I saw that "The client and the server must ignore any unknown fields in messages", but it doesn't say anything about missing fields. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The "errors" part of the spec talks about that.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md#errors